# Assign customer to group based on product bought

Tags: customer-group

Is it possible via some extension or modification to assign customer to a customer group based on the product he buys? For example if we have a "Membership 2015" product and we need to automatically assign customers who buy that product to the "Members 2015" customer group. This way we could set up a catalog price rule that would give discounts for any customers that belong to the Members 2015 group.

Comment: I'm looking for a very similar solution.  Although mine might not be based on membership purchased, I want to add a customer to a group based on specific physical products purchased.

My use case is that customers who purchase a particular product will get a lifetime discount on certain other add-on products or replacement parts.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up with using modified version of this extension:
http://mageshopapps.com/shop/customer-membership.html

However here is another extension that should do the job without modifications:
https://plugin.company/magento-extensions/automatic-customer-group-switching.html